# integer division operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog, clpfd

This code is a part of the program that I am writing to solve a cryptarithmatic puzzle in prolog. I am solving this using CLPFD (SICStus Prolog). I am getting an error while using the inbuilt integer division operator "//" (See Below for details). I was not able to solve this So I wrote my own integer division function.

**What I want to know is why "//" fails**. There is no such problem with the other arithmetic operators like +, - , /

**BEFORE:**

```
solve1([],[],[H],H).
solve([H1],[H2],[H3,H4],C) :- H1 #\= 0, H2 #\= 0,
                              H3 #= (C+H1+H2)mod 10,
                              H4 #=(C+H1+H2)//10.

solve([H1|T1] , [H2|T2] , [H3|T3],C) :- H3 #= (C+H1+H2)mod 10,
                                        C1 #=(C+H1+H2)//10 ,
                                        solve(T1,T2,T3,C1).
```

This is the error I get

**ERROR:** Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found`(0+_G1592+_G1586)//10'
Exception: (12) throw(error(domain_error(clpfd_expression, (0+_G3994{0..9}+_G3991{0..9})//10), _G3976)) ?

**AFTER:**

```
integer_div(N,M) :- M #= N/10 , integer(M).
integer_div(N,M) :- N1 #= N mod 10 , N2 #= N-N1 , M #= N2/10.


solve1([],[],[H],H).
solve([H1],[H2],[H3,H4],C) :- H1 #\= 0, H2 #\= 0,
                              H3 #= (C+H1+H2)mod 10,
                              integer_div((C+H1+H2),H4).

solve([H1|T1] , [H2|T2] , [H3|T3],C) :- H3 #= (C+H1+H2)mod 10,
                                        integer_div((C+H1+H2),C1) ,
                                        solve(T1,T2,T3,C1).
```

This works perfectly All I did was replace "//" by my own version of integer division

Comment: Since 4.3.0, `(//)/2` is a valid operator in SICStus' clpfd

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282%2c%20%27A.7%27%2c%20swi%28%27%2fdoc%2fManual%2fclpfd.html%27%29%29), CLP-FD uses / for integer division.

Comment: Have you actually Tested this? I don't think this is the integer division because if it was, my integer_div function wouldn't have worked. I have used / operator there and it acts as a division operator

Comment: I am afraid this is not at all Helpful

Comment: Well a simple test says that single `/` really is integer division: `?- T#=3, U#=T/2,labeling([], [T,U]).`